# Angular JS setting a base API URL for requests

Tags: angularjs, symfony

i am building an AngularJS app this is what i have atm:

App.js

```
var youtubeTrackerApp = angular.module('youtubeTrackerApp', [
    'youtubeTrackerControllers',
    'youtubeTrackerServices'
]);
```

Services.js

```
var youtubeTrackerServices = angular.module('youtubeTrackerServices', ['ngResource']);

youtubeTrackerServices.factory('YouTubeVideo', function($http) {
    var YouTubeVideo = function(data) {
        angular.extend(this, data);
    }

    YouTubeVideo.get = function(id) {
        return $http.get('/Api/YouTubeVideo/' + id).then(function(response) {
            return new YouTubeVideo(response.data);
        });
    };

    YouTubeVideo.prototype.create = function() {
        var youTubeVideo = this;
        return $http.post('Api/YouTubeVideo/', youTubeVideo).then(function(response) {
            youTubeVideo.id = response.data.id;
            return youTubeVideo;
        });
    }

    return YouTubeVideo;
});
```

The issue is that Angular is posting like this:

```
http://localhost/Api/YouTubeVideo/123
```

And while i am developing, i  need it to post to

```
http://localhost/youtubetracker/web/app_dev.php/Api/YouTubeVideo/123
```

Since i am using Symfony. I am quite new to AngularJS, the and i cant seem to figure out how to inject a base URL between the localhost and endpoint.

Any other tips combining Symfony and Angular are welcome.

Comment: You could use a provider, in this way you could set the base API url during the config phase: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers#provider-recipe

Answer (score 0):

when using a PHP end point i would suggest hacking into the .htaccess file

Something like this

RewriteEngine On

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php?x=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php [QSA,NC,L]
```

http.get youtubetracker/web/app_dev/Api/YouTubeVideo/123
php api file in youtubetracker/web/app_dev/Api/
im assuming that YouTubeVideo & 123 params